# what's the port number of mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-strings

I'm trying to connect mysql with vb.net, I've already downloaded the  mysql connector-net. And installed it. 
But I don't know what  is the port number , server address of mysql. Its needed in the connection string. Please help,

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: I don't suppose you thought to check the MySQL docs? Besides, if MySQL is running on the default port there is no need to specify it in the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

Default is 3306, however default installation of mysql only listen on localhost or has "skip-networking" enabled.

Comment: What is skip networking.

Comment: @user28233, If skip networking is enabled then you cannot connect to the mysql server through the network.

Comment: how do I disable it?This is only a single computer with wamp server installed. I'm not trying to connect to the server computer.